# Product of Covariant and Contravariant rank 2 Tensors

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, covariance

By the definition, 
Contravariant tensor transforms like

$ (A')^{ij}=\sum_{k,l}{\frac{\partial (x')^i}{\partial x^k}\frac{\partial (x')^j}{\partial x^l}A^{kl}}$

Covariant tensor transforms like

$ (A')_{ij}=\sum_{k,l}{\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial (x')^i}\frac{\partial x^l}{\partial (x')^j}A_{kl}}$

We can make similarity transformation as matrix multiplication by the following product of tensors

$ (A')_{ij}=\sum_{k,l}{S_{ik}A^{kl}(S^T)_{lj}}$

I heard that when we product each tensor, we must put repeated indexed separated as one up and one down ( $A^{\mu\nu} B_{\mu\nu}$ ) so that it become invariant under transformation.

I'm curious that " How about the products of tensors like $A^{\mu\nu} B^{\mu\nu}$ or $A_{\mu\nu} B_{\mu\nu}$  ? "

It will not be invariant under transformation, but can't we just define those products?

Why I came with this question is the following :

When we discuss about the product of antisymmetric & symmetric tensor as $A^{\mu\nu} S^{\mu\nu}$
( where $A^{\mu\nu}$ is antisymmetric tensor and $S^{\mu\nu}$ is symmetric tensor )

We can see  $A^{\mu\nu} S^{\mu\nu}=0$ by the following procedure :

$A^{\mu\nu} S^{\mu\nu}=-A^{\nu\mu} S^{\mu\nu}=A^{\mu\nu} S^{\nu\mu}=-A^{\mu\nu} S^{\mu\nu}=0 $

However, I'm suspicious that "Is $A^{\mu\nu} S^{\mu\nu}$ the possible form of product of tensors?"

Answer (score 1):

The transformation you wrote down is not a matrix  [similarity transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity), it is a [matrix congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence) transformation. The other expression you wrote down, summing indices at the same level, are not  tensors unless you restric yourself to orthogonal transformations, in which case similary and congrunce transformations are the same thing..

Comment: I thought the transformation I wrote was "similarity transformation", because in Arfken 7th edition (Mathematical Methods for Physicists), they introduce such transformation as "similarity transformation"

Comment: Also, I know that $A^{\mu \nu} B ^{\mu \nu}$ is not a tensor but I was curious that such form can be possible to make or define...

Comment: Similarity is $A\to B^{-1} A B$ and transforms  linear maps, i,e matrices with  with tensor structure ${A^a}_b$.  Congrence $A\to B^TAB$ is  for quadratic forms, i.e matrices  with tensor structure $A_{ab}$.